# Why do I get the error "Preflash Validation Failed" when trying to install a ROM on my Moto G8 Power?

Tags: rom-flashing, fastboot, motorola-moto-g, android-12

I was trying to install an [Android 12 GSI](https://ci.android.com/builds/submitted/7947797/aosp_arm64-userdebug/latest/aosp_arm64-img-7947797.zip) with Fastboot, but whenever I try to install the system.img, it always fails with the error:

> (bootloader) Preflash validation failed
> FAILED (remote failure)

I have seen that this error is common if you have the bootloader locked, but mine is unlocked.

Here's the full list of commands I used:

```
F:\Programs\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot flash boot boot.img
target reported max download size of 805261312 bytes
sending 'boot_b' (52224 KB)...
OKAY [  1.276s]
writing 'boot_b'...
OKAY [  0.779s]
finished. total time: 2.056s

F:\Programs\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot flash vbmeta vbmeta.img
target reported max download size of 805261312 bytes
sending 'vbmeta_b' (4 KB)...
OKAY [  0.005s]
writing 'vbmeta_b'...
(bootloader) WARNING: vbmeta_b anti rollback downgrade, 0 vs 16
OKAY [  0.036s]
finished. total time: 0.041s

F:\Programs\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>fastboot flash system system.img
target reported max download size of 805261312 bytes
Invalid sparse file format at header magic
sending sparse 'system_b' 1/3 (786340 KB)...
OKAY [ 19.870s]
writing 'system_b' 1/3...
(bootloader) Preflash validation failed
FAILED (remote failure)
finished. total time: 19.962s
```

Why do I get this error, and is there any way to solve it?